# android tachograph

Tags: android, serial-port

I would like to connect Android device to a tachograph's RS232 serial port. Is it possible to do that without Android device being rooted? Is there any sample code of that kind of connection?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See your options here: http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/wiki/android_to_rs232_guideline.

Non-rooted options are:

- Bluetooth -> RS232
- A USB Host -> UART adapter. E.g IOIO https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10748

Comment: Thanks, I decided to try with the first option. I bought a rs232 to bluetooth adapter from serialIO. Then i created a simple android app to connect to bluetooth side of the adapter and connected the tachograph maschine to rs232. Now, the tachograph expects to receive 5 bytes (in hex: 81, e6, f0, 81, e0). The problem is, &H81 in bytes equals 129 and that is overflow for android max value of byte(127). Now i don't know how to send those bytes. Thanks